# How to change speed/velocity of camera?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm using a-frame-extras universal-controls & look-controls. Can anyone tell me how to find the attribute to change the walking speed of the camera? 
Many thanks.

See the Pen Coral by Mark (@MannyMeadows) on CodePen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [universal-controls](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls) component is a replacement for both `look-controls` and `wasd-controls`, so you probably don't want to use both at the same time.

To adjust the speed of `wasd-controls`, use `wasd-controls="acceleration: 100"`. [Documentation for `wasd-controls`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/wasd-controls.html).

To adjust the speed of `universal-controls`, use `universal-controls="movementAcceleration: 100"`. [Options for `universal-controls`](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/controls/universal-controls.js#L20-L29).

In both cases, changes will not affect speed for roomscale tracking.

Comment: Hi Don ! Is it possible to update your answer ? universal-controls has changed to movement-controls, and i can't find how to completely remove the velocity when using WASD. Thank you :)